# Can you access a property of an object as a value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
var obj = { 'first':'1st', 'second':'2nd', 'third':'3rd', ...}
```

I know that accessing the value of an object's property is...

```
obj.first || obj["first"] //returns '1st' as a value
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to access the property as a value without iterating through the whole *var obj* to make a new *var* that has the property switched with the value. It would just be a whole new obj.

Is this possible? Have I given enough context? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: `var newObject = Object.assign( {}, obj, { first: 'newValue' } );`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can't, but you could create a second object for the reverse mapping and populate it once with a loop (or even add the properties back to the original object).

Comment: You can access the value if you know the key (property), if you want to know what the key is you must either know it in prior or loop the object and find out all the keys that exist. I dont see any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Since an object is, well, an `Object`, you can pull the whole object keys into an Array, and then pull the one which is right for you..

Using the `Object.keys()` method you can access to the keys of your object, then, using the `Array.indexOf()` method you will pull which is right for you.

### A Short Example

```js
function getKey(obj, key) {
  var arr = Object.keys(obj);
  var result = '';
  if (arr.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
    var index = arr.indexOf(key);
    result = arr[index];
    return result;
  }
  return null;
}

var obj = {
  'first': '1st',
  'second': '2nd',
  'third': '3rd'
}

console.log(getKey(obj, 'first'));
```

### See:

- [MDN Object.keys() Ref.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [A CodePen example](http://codepen.io/liorgrs/pen/JXBzLO?editors=0012)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want to bind an objects property to another object's property so that when `o1.first` changes `o2.first` changes automatically. That would be possible with arranging the setter of `o1.first` property. A simple way to achieve this with object litereals would be like

```
var o1 = {
           _first: "1st",
           second: "2nd",
            third: "3rd",
            get first() {
                  return this._first
                },
            set first(v) {
                  this._first = v;
                  o2.first = v;
                }
         },
    o2 = {first:""};
console.log(o1) // Object {_first: "1st", second: "2nd", third: "3rd"}
console.log(o2) // Object {first: ""}
o1.first = yes;
console.log(o1) // Object {_first: "yes", second: "2nd", third: "3rd"}
console.log(o2) // Object {first: "yes"}
o1["first"] = "once again"; // "once again"
console.log(o2["first"]);   // "once again"
```

For more information on JS object getters and setters have a look at https://robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-getters-setters.html